# Laravel PDF Bootstrap

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, pdf

Llevo un par de días intentando genera un código `html` más `css` ayudandome de `bootstrap` para realizar una facutra consolidada y que parezca de empresa pero no soy capaz.

Busque y encontre que con `Barrydvh` en `Laravel` es incompatible que me instalara `snappy`, pero da igual se ve de la sigueinte manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre que no aplica nada de `css` y se sale del marco del folio la verdad que no va por buen camino.

Queria saber si existe alguna manera de aplicarle `bootstrap` o tiene que ser todo por `css` y `html` puro y duro.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver, para el problema que tienes en específico, puedes utilizar esta herramienta: https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Invoices. Hay un archivo blade que puedes modificar a tu antojo con Bootstrap y las variables que quieras generar con los datos del cliente. La librería hará todo el trabajo de convertir el HTML en PDF sin problema.

La documentación es bastante sencilla e intuitiva: https://erik.cat/projects/Invoices/docs/1

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema viene por las rutas del blade del PDF, que no son las mismas que el resto.
Prueba a hacer

```
  <style>
        <?php include( public_path() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );?>
    </style>
```